# JS. How to collect each required element from an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, string

I am making a tokenizer that builds an abstract tree and I want to collect all the "text" from an array that is output by my tokenizer.

Output:

```
{
  "error": false,
  "tokens": [
    {
      "type": "keyword",
      "value": "print",
      "text": "print"
    },
    {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "hello world",
      "text": "hello world"
    },
    {
      "type": "keyword",
      "value": "var",
      "text": "var"
    },
    {
      "type": "keyword_valueof",
      "value": "msg",
      "text": "msg"
    },
    {
      "type": "operator",
      "value": "eq",
      "text": "="
    },
    {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "secret message",
      "text": "secret message"
    }...
```

It should turn out like this:

```
print "hello world"
var msg = "secret message"
```

Can you help me, I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Can you provide some of the code you've tried to write? Also can you explain the shape of the output you're trying to achieve a bit more as it's confusing.

Comment: I tried using loops tokens.text nr didn’t work, because it always showed me [object Object], and here you need to collect and display all the lines of "text" from the array. The output should be like this: print "hello world"
var msg = "secret message"

Comment: I'm looking at it and I understand now  however the output of your tokenizer doesn't appear to encode a new line. you could do `output.tokens.map(e => e.text).join(" ")` to join it all together but I still think fundamentally you're missing information in your tokenization

Comment: I don't think you're missing any information to achieve your desired output. The `type` property is enough to print newlines and quotes

Comment: no, he told the truth, here we need attributes like a new line, line feed, so that everything is displayed beautifully and correctly.

Comment: @Tim that can be derived from the `type`.

Comment: knowing only the type, we cannot properly display the information. More information needed, information about new lines and line indexing, the type is simply created so that in case of an error it shows that some line in the line does not match the line, and then

Comment: @IanBrindley I don't think it could be without knowing the language specification it's neither javascript nor python

Comment: Why would you accept an answer that doesn't answer your question? IMO, that makes this question not useful.

Comment: @ThomasSablik he answers my question, the task was to collect and withdraw, and this task has already been solved, you can close the question.

Comment: _Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. [...] With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed, high-quality answers to every question about programming._ The goal is not to solve your problem, but to help future users. You commented: _the output is not quite what was expected, but thanks!_ It may have solved your problem, but it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: this is not a personal error of the one who answered, but of the one who asked, I did not parse newlines, and therefore the result was not what was expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to extract each value of the "text" to an array, you can use the map() method:

```
const arr = obj.tokens.map((token) => token.text);
```

Where 'obj' is the main object (with the "errors" and "tokens" keys).
To print each element of the array in a new line:

```
arr.forEach(elem => {console.log(elem);});
```

e.g.:

```js
const obj = {
  "error": false,
  "tokens": [
    {
      "type": "...",
      "value": "...",
      "text": "text 1"
    },
    {
      "type": "...",
      "value": "...",
      "text": "text 2"
    }
  ]
}

const tokensArr = obj.tokens.map(token => token.text);
tokensArr.forEach(elem => {console.log(elem);});
```

Comment: the output is not quite what was expected, but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```js
let array = ["secretMessage", "anotherMessage"]; //The array
let theNumberIdOfMessage = 0; //The first item of the array

console.log(array[theNumberIdOfMessage]); //Get the item first in the array and log it

theNumberIdOfMessage = 1; //The second item of the array

console.log(array[theNumberIdOfMessage]); //Log the second item
```

Comment: no, not really, here the element is collected by index, but I need to find and collect all rows "text" without an index.